# Photogrammetry software for defining polygons manually

Tags: 3d

I would like to have 3D model of a building. Problem is that its walls are very uniform of one color so photogrammetry software has problem to detect these areas into point-clouds.

I would like to define these walls manually in the software so in next step texturing will process them.

I have tried Photomodeller as it has the option but I did not have much luck with the process. Zephyr3D does not have this option. Is there also other software with this option? Other specific features are not needed. (preferably free/demo)

The software should preferably run on Linux or Windows (wine emulation works quite well). Price limit: that depends on features, 200e max for single license.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a steep learning curve but [Blender 3D](https://www.blender.org/) can do the job and more:

1. Model from coordinates
2. Apply photo textures
3. lots more.

You may find [this tutorial](https://cgi.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-3d-floor-plan-model-from-an-architectural-schematic-in-blender--cg-13350) useful and there are a huge number of tutorial pages, videos, books & courses available *at various costs from free upwards.*

- Price: Free, Gratis (plus open source)
- Platform: Linux, Windows & Mac

Comment: It is a way. But it is a way in different direction. It requires drawing it all from scratch and "Photogrammetry" is about doing this all instead of you - from the photos. So I would like to find a way for it using this approach.

Comment: @MiroJanosik https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=km7ko2yddx8 may help

Comment: Nice ideas with Blender, though ... my building does not have too much leveled walls (surface is slope, roof is tiled) so it may cause me some troubles. Also, video(and other I found) all rely only single photo .. is there some approach which would do more with multiple photos please?